# Big load time on simple SELECT query but in phpmyadmin it's fast

Tags: mariadb

Simple SELECT mariadb query takes 16-30~ seconds on both terminal and php script but in phpmyadmin loads in 0.016

```
SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE post_id = '22931'
```

Database size ~ 4GB. Worked perfectly fine till today when I had to restart the sever.

[image]

Comment: `EXPLAIN` it to find out more.

Comment: Does it take that much time once you've connected, or that much time to connect?

Comment: Once connected. Any query takes 16-30seconds, doesn't matter if blob value is 10kb or 1mb. Everything works instantly on phpmyadmin. Between 0.5-0.7 for uncached to instant for cached query. On terminal/php script any query takes 16-30 seconds. I don't know what to explain is very weird and don't have a clue what to even explain.

Comment: Are you sure it's the exact same database server? What version of MariaDB? Does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show any unusual activity? Does `SELECT 1` run slowly, too?

Comment: everything was the same. I have reinstalled the server without phpmyadmin, works flawlessly now. (tested the DB on other server and it was working fine there so I decided to reinstall everything).

"Does SELECT 1 run slowly, too" NO. other tables with less data were working fine.